# How to solve ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT when deploying django rest framework web app to Azure?

Tags: django, azure, heroku, django-rest-framework, web-applications

I deployed an web app which django restframework base on Heroku and Azure.

Same app on Heroku works fine.

But when I access to Azure, it causes ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT error.

I googled and found that turn SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT off solved ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT error.
However, it causes 403 CSRF error instead.

I need to find another way to fix ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT or find a way to fix 403 CSRF error.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Thank you comment, but it doesn't solve my problem, since I use django restframework, I don't have to edit template at all

Answer (score 2):

If your app is on "Azure App Service", the HTTPS connection will be terminated before it reaches your web worker. Your app wil see an incoming HTTP request instead. In this case you need to set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False` indeed. If you want to enforce HTTPS (which is a good practice) you can do so in the Azure settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings#enforce-https

About the CSRF-related error: because Azure translates HTTPS to HTTP, you need to configure Django to allow POST requests from a different scheme ([since Django 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0)) by adding this to `settings.py`:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://YOUR-DOMAIN.com", "https://www.YOUR-DOMAIN.com"]
```

If this does not solve your problem, you can temporarily set `DEBUG = True` in production and try again. On the error page, you will see a "Reason given for failure" that you can post here.

Comment: Thank you for comment, It is very useful. After I turn HTTPS only option on, both Redirect and CSRF problem solved. I still set SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT as False though.

Comment: Thank you.  SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT setting for the win!